# Including an assembly in a VS 2013 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, assemblies

This question may seem like a duplicate, but I have tried all answers I found and my problem still exists.

I build a web application (VS 2013 .net 4.0) that uses some Microsoft.SqlServer assemblies (smo, management etc.). These assemblies do not exists on the server I am deploying the app to (and at this point, I was asked to do so without installing them in the GAC).

I have tried setting the copy Local = True (which was the most recommended answer I could find). In VS 2010/2013 on the project properties publish tab I do not see the Publish status.
When I publish the app (file system) The DLL's are in the Bin folder. My understanding is that if when I set it the local copy = true, it will look in the Bin folder.

Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: Do you have some sort of installer package that should be installing your dependencies?  I haven't built a web app in a long time, but with winforms apps, I used to have to arrange my Installation project and make sure my dependent DLL files were being put in my _application_ folder

Comment: How did you reference the dll's? If you referenced them from the GAC on your machine it might be trying to look at the GAC on the server. Try copying the dll to a folder local to your project and update the references in VS to point to the local copy.

Comment: This is your answer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx. All copy local does - copies assembly into `TargetDir`. Having it there is the safe bet that it will be found on the machine, which will run your code. It is much easier to understand when working with your DLLs only. They are in `TargetDir`, not in GAC. And they are found by your executable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and sorry for the late response. 1. I don't have an installer package, I use publish app to file and then I copy the files to the server. 2. I tried the approach of having the assembly files in the project directory and referencing them from that directory. I used copy local and confirmed the DLL's are both in the bin folder and in the project directory. However I am still getting the error : "Could not load file or assembly 'xxxx, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: resolved... the assemblies were loaded correctly from the Bin folder. Thanks T.S and Dave Zych . The last issue I had to work through was the microsoft.sqlserver.sqlClrProvider dll.. that is also resolved.